# Snowflake Ordering on Text seems Incorrect

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and have noticed the ordering on text columns does not behave as expected.

Take this simple example:

```
select *
    from ( values ('ab'), ('aBc'), ('acd') ) t(col1)
order by col1
```

Expected order: ab, aBc, acd

Actual order: **aBc**, ab, acd

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use COLLATE specification directly in the order by clause.

The collate lets you specify following configuration settings to be used when comparing values:

- Locale
- Case-sensitivity
- Accent-sensitivity
- Punctuation-sensitivity
- First-letter preference
- Case-conversion
- Space-trimming

Following example uses English Locale(en) and Case Insensitive(ci) collation:

```
select *
    from ( values ('ab'), ('aBc'), ('acd'), ('Z') ) t(col1)
   order by collate(col1, 'en-ci');
```

Result returned:

ab
aBc
acd
Z

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/order-by.html):

> All data is sorted according to the numeric byte value of each character in the ASCII table. UTF-8 encoding is supported.

In the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), `B` comes before `b`.

It's weird the `order by` didn't consider the string length in the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

This will also sort "Z" before "a" because it's first in ASCII / Unicode order. You can order by with an upper function:

```
select *
    from ( values ('ab'), ('aBc'), ('acd'), ('Z') ) t(col1)
order by col1
```

To sort without case sensitivity, you can use the upper or lower function.

```
select *
    from ( values ('ab'), ('aBc'), ('acd'), ('Z') ) t(col1)
order by upper(col1)
```